# Convert Excel file into Dataframe and then convert into Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel file that is in the advanced format:

[image]

The task is to read the Excel file and convert it into the Simple Excel Format using Python:

[image]

I have tried with the Pandas library but I am stuck.

Input File: [Input File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eGqPT9BrSw8V-oW6QBiSBSiGw2t5zvF9/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=114665555954676159614&rtpof=true&sd=true)
Output File: [Output File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xm7k720uzujwmZnvj6ydGSsY7vK6sPgM/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=114665555954676159614&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: To be honest, writing this post has probably taken longer than looking up one of the hundreds of similar questions. Don't expect other people to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with something like:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load data:
data = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx")

# Shape before split:
data["DATE"] = data["DATE"].ffill()
data.loc[4, "DATE"] = "DATE"
data = data.dropna()

# Split AM/PM:
slice1 = data.loc[0:2, :]
slice2 = data.loc[4:, :]
slice2.columns = slice2.loc[4, :]
slice2 = slice2.drop(4)

# Assemble AM & PM:
data = slice1.merge(slice2, on=["DATE", "Time"])

# Normalize:
records = data.melt(id_vars=["DATE", "Time"])
```

It returns the expected table. Now it is just about saving the file.

```
records.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```